# C++ non-specialized member in template class

Tags: c++, templates, specialization, dllexport, partial-specialization

I have a question about template classes.
For example, take this class

```
template<class TBase> class CTemplateInherit : public TBase
{
public:

    virtual void DoNonSpecializedWork();
    virtual void DoTemplateWork();
    virtual ~CTemplateInherit();
};

// In header file
template<class TBase>
bool CTemplateInherit<TBase>::DoTemplateWork()
{
    std::wcout << L"CTemplateInherit::DoTemplateWork" << std::endl;
    TBase::DoWork();
    return true;
}

// In CPP file
bool CTemplateInherit::DoNonSpecializedWork()
{
    std::wcout << L"CTemplateInherit::DoNonSpecializedWork" << std::endl;
    return true;
}
```

Now, I would like to be able to define non-specialized methods in a CPP file with dllexport, and just keep the specializations in the header.
Normally, I suppose I could just define member methods as templated, but since I'm inheriting from TBase that isn't possible.

So how would I be able the split this up? I only override maybe 4 methods from TBase, and would like to be able to keep the other 40 or so methods as DLLEXPORT in the DLL, while the specializations are in the header file.

Thank you in advance for your suggestions!

Comment: `CTemplateInherit::DoNonSpecializedWork` without template parameter shouldn't compile, right?

Comment: Maybe just create an intermediate non-templated `TNonspecialized`, where you implement all the non-specialized methods, and declare `template<class TBase> class CTemplateInherit : public TBase, public TNonspecialized`?

Comment: Thank you! No, it doesn't compile of course. It was more like what I wanted to do. I was thinking about inheriting from two classes, but then a function call to one member function would be ambiguous. Though I'm still thinking about doing something along those lines like you suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is one important piece of information missing: Are the non-specialized methods overriding virtual methods of the `TBase` class? This is the central issue here.

If not, then you can just create another class for the non-specialized methods, and inherit (publicly) from both classes in your `CTemplateInherit` class. Problem solved.

If, however, the non-specialized methods override virtual methods of the TBase class, then it is only slightly more complicated:

Solution 1) Take all the non-specialized functions and regroup them into one "detail" header. Either as a group of (non-template) free-functions (if it is easy enough to just pass input-outputs as parameters) or as a (non-template) class with the non-specialized data members it requires. Then, you define all those functions (implement them) inside a corresponding cpp file (which you will later compile into the DLL).

Then, in your `CTemplateInherit` class template, simply forward the non-specialized function calls to the set of "detail" functions. Because templates inline by default, the overhead will be nil. If you needed to regroup the "detail" functions into one class (non-template), then, simply use `private` inheritance, preventing function-name conflicts. Then, you can access the data members of the "detail" class like any other inherited data member, and you can forward the non-specialized function calls to the "detail" class implementation which you can compile into a DLL (if you have a suitable framework for exporting classes from a DLL (because plain C++ doesn't have a reliable mechanism for that), but your question seems to imply that you do).

The only issue with this solution is the annoying creation of several simple forwarding functions. But IMHO, that is a reasonable price to pay for tucking away an implementation in a DLL (almost any time you want to do that, you end up writing a bunch of wrapper functions).

Solution 2) If there is a set of non-specialized virtual functions from the base class, then that subset is certainly not dependent on the actual type of `TBase` (I mean, the prototypes of those functions can be formed without it). Then, it means that you can regroup that subset of functions into another base-class from which `TBase` is expected to be inheriting from. Let's call it `TNonSpecialBase`. At this point, you can set up the following hierarchy:

```
class TNonSpecialBase {
  // set of pure-virtual functions that are not special.
};

// this is an example of a class that could act as a TBase:
class TExampleBase : public virtual TNonSpecialBase {
  // set of virtual functions that are special to TExampleBase.
};

class CNonSpecialDerived : public virtual TNonSpecialBase {
  // declaration of non-specialized functions that override the function in TNonSpecialBase.
};

template <typename TBase>
class CTemplateInherit : public TBase, public CNonSpecialDerived {
  // set of virtual functions that are specialized for the template argument TBase.
};
```

With the above setup, the specialized functions must end up in the header file of `CTemplateInherit`, but the non-specialized functions, regrouped in `CNonSpecialDerived` can be defined in a separate cpp file (and compiled into a DLL). The magic trick here is the use of the virtual inheritance to allow for the final class to have a single virtual-table for the base class `TNonSpecialBase`. In other words, this allows the class `CNonSpecialDerived` to override the virtual functions in TBase which are inherited from `TNonSpecialBase`, as long as TBase does not override any of those functions (in which case, the compiler will call it ambiguous). This way the user can deal with a pointer to a `TBase` object, call any of its virtual functions, which will cause either a dispatch towards the `CTemplateInherit` implementations (specialized) or the `CNonSpecialDerived` implementations (presumably, in the DLL).

Comment: Thank you so much! This is what I ended up doing. Inheriting from TBase and a non-templated class. Essentially, the class is supposed to serve as a derived class with extended functionality, but mutiple classes may use it. If I could upload an image here, I would for demonstration purposes.

Comment: Thanks. Please see the edited post above (I cannot answer without 10 reputation points).

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to change `hierarchy` of your classes.

1) `specialize` your function for all needed types in `.cpp` file.

```
template<>
bool CTemplateInherit<First>::DoNonSpecializedWork()
{
    std::wcout << L"CTemplateInherit::DoNonSpecializedWork" << std::endl;
    return true;
}

template<>
bool CTemplateInherit<Second>::DoNonSpecializedWork()
{
    std::wcout << L"CTemplateInherit::DoNonSpecializedWork" << std::endl;
    return true;
}

template<>
bool CTemplateInherit<Nth>::DoNonSpecializedWork()
{
    std::wcout << L"CTemplateInherit::DoNonSpecializedWork" << std::endl;
    return true;
}
```

2) Use

```
template<typename T>
bool CTemplateInherit<T>::DoNonSpecializedWork()
{
    std::wcout << L"CTemplateInherit::DoNonSpecializedWork" << std::endl;
    return true;
}
```

in `.cpp` file, but use something like this in `header`

```
template class CTemplateInherit<First>;
template class CTemplateInherit<Second>;
template class CTemplateInherit<Nth>;
```

3) As **Dietmar** suggest.

Comment: Thanks. Please see the edited post above (I cannot answer without 10 reputation points).

Answer (score 3):

I'm not quite sure what you try to accomplish but when using templates you need to make sure that these are instantiated as necessary. When you put the template definition in the header, you can get implicit instantiation from the compiler: Whenever it sees that a function template is used and there is a definition of this template visible, it will instantiate the template. When you put templates somewhere else the compiler won't see the template definition when it is needed and, thus, won't implicitly instantiate it. However, you can instantiate the corresponding function templates yourself, e.g.:

```
// In CPP file
template <class TBase>
bool CTemplateInherit<TBase>::DoNonSpecializedWork()
{
    std::wcout << L"CTemplateInherit::DoNonSpecializedWork" << std::endl;
    return true;
}

template bool CTemplateInherit<SomeBase>::DoNotSpecializeWork();
template bool CTemplateInherit<SomeOtherBase>::DoNotSpecializeWork();
```

Comment: Maybe I should clarify why this is what I want (need).
There are non-specialized methods that access resources defined in the DLL, so if I define those in the header, then they won't find resources when used with LoadString(), for example.
So that is why I have the need for them to be defined and executed in the context of the DLL.

I think that inheriting from two bases would possibly make the most sense in that case, no?

Comment: Thanks. Please see the edited post above (I cannot answer without 10 reputation points).